# Codeigniter and AJAX MySQL Error Handling

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, error-handling

I'm (new to) using CI3 and have created a simple form that will insert a single value (`age`) into a MySQL database (`test`) table. I don't have any front end validation in the form, I'm experimenting with server side validation.

The `age` column has the following attributes in the database;

- name: age
- datatype: int
- allow non null: no
- default: no default

Whenever I enter a non numeric value in the form input `age` (e.g. 'john'), the form submits successfully, but the database saves this value as a `0`. **Is this expected behavior?**

It seems I am able to enter a non integer to the database although it's setup as a datatype `int`.

I would have expected the following error to be thrown;

> /* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'john' in 'where clause' */

This error (as expected) appears whenever I try to manually insert a non int value (via heidisql / phpmyadmin).

So, how can I check for this error in my application, and take action accordingly?

My code is below;

**Model**

```
public function insert_form_data(){
    $data = array(
        'age'  => $this->input->post('age')
    );
    $result = $this->db->insert('test', $data);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        return $this->db->error(); 
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function insert_form_data(){
    $data = $this->Form_model->insert_form_data();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**View**

```
<form name="myform" id="myform">
    <input name="age" type="text">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<p id="message"></p>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "form/insert_form_data",
            method: "post",
            data: $("#myform").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response == true) {
                    $('#message').text('Form submitted!');
                }
            },
            error: function(response) {}
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: try dumping $data before you insert so you can see what that is, if it is john, then maybe its something CI specific ( i havent used it in years so my knowledge is rusty)

Comment: u forgot to add ID in `<form>` as `<form name="myform" id="myform">` second, your error not relate to question, where in INSERT QUERY? for error, check error logs inside `application` folder

Comment: WHERE clause error in INSERT query?

Comment: use CI validation

Comment: thanks but that doesn't answer my question @devpro

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wanna depend on sql errors while you have everything you might need in codeigniter's validation library for checking before insertion like this:

```
public function insert_form_data()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('age', 'Age', 'required|integer');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $data['validation'] = validation_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        $data['validation'] = "Success";
    }
    $data["result"] = $this->Form_model->insert_form_data();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sherif Salah but that doesn't answer my question. I'm able to submit a non integer into my database even though I have specified `int` as the datatype.

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek, here is your query `INSERT INTO \`table\` (\`age\`) VALUES ('hello')` and if you run it on `phpMyAdmin` it won't give you an error and would still save it as zero, so it is not a codeigniter's problem.

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek You are right, no validation at the database end.. it casts it as an int by default as you specified which will always be 0 in case of a string and that's it.. that's why i told you to forget about it and depend on codeigniter's validation or extend it with your own if it doesn't have what you need and just pass pure data to your database.

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek we are already commenting under the answer :D

Comment: If you leave an answer I can accept and it may help others :)